# Subfloor question

Tags: subfloor

Can new tongue-n-groove subfloor be butted up against old non-T&G subfloor?   And still maintain structural integrity for tile?

Details:

```
Remolding bathroom.

Moving toilet, bathtub and shower feeds to new locations so had to open floor.

Old subfloor was solid and never creaked nor tiles ever came loose.

Hate to rip up good subfloor in closets and other areas and risk changing any more structural integrity .
```

Thinking of sliding groove end of new plywood under wall frame to mate with tongue of existing plywood (under wall frame).  Butt side to existing subfloor and in picture.

[image: my_idea]

Comment: Make sure you install the face grain perpendicular to the joists.

Comment: @Lee Sam  Can I ask why face grain perpendicular to the joists?

Comment: Plywood is made from “layers” (plies) of lumber veneer, which are laid up with the plies 90 degrees to each other. You’ll notice the outer most plies (top and bottom) run in the same direction. This makes the plywood more than twice as strong when spanning perpendicular to the joists as when spanning parallel to the joists. If you don’t, the floor will feel spongy (and sag badly) when you walk on it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it will be well-supported by floor joists, so I would not have a problem doing this.
I can't see everything at the bottom of your picture, but it would be important to me to have the corners of your replacement subfloor supported. I've had to add blocking perpendicular to the joists in order to meet this before but it looks like you might have about 3/4" of joist to support the edge of your new plywood and that would be sufficient.

If you can spare some floor depth, I also recommend using a backer board for tile on top of the subfloor (your question doesn't say whether you were considering this or not). You can use the thin stuff (1/4" or 3/8" is enough) the 1/2" stuff is for walls and primarily to match the thickness of drywall. Check out install guides for the backer or concrete boards, I think it says to install with seams perpendicular to your subfloor seam direction.

Comment: Thanks.  There is 1/4" on top of the 3/4" plywood (although not in this picture).  My plan was to do the following: 3/4" ply->1/4" ply over joints->Schluter®-DITRA-HEAT->ceramic tile.